# using celery with flask_restful

Tags: python, api, celery, flask-restful

i have a simple flask restful API where I want to execute the request as Celery task since some endpoints need a lot of execution time.

main.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_celery import make_celery

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0',
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

celery = make_celery(app)
api = Api(app)

api.add_resource(someResource, '/someendpoint/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

with make_celery.py:

```
from celery import Celery

def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(
        app.import_name,
        backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'],
        broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL']
    )
    celery.conf.update(app.config)

    class ContextTask(celery.Task):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

I now want to define that the Resource I defined in resource.py is a celery task:

```
class Cost(Resource):

    def get(self):

        result = some_code 

        return result
```

what is the most convenient way to make the get method a celery task here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have the same question. Do you have any leads on this?